# How can I convert a pointer to an array allocated in a C++ function into an array in Rust?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I am writing Rust code that interfaces with a C++ API. I am calling a specific C++ function that allocates some memory then returns it to me. The function has the following signature:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "C" fn native_fn(
    count: c_uint, 
    data: *mut *mut NativeStructType
)
```

where it allocates `count` items of type `NativeStructType` then modifies the given pointer to point to an array of pointers to those objects. I call it as follows:

```rust
let mut ptr = 0 as *mut NativeStructType;
native_fn(2, &mut ptr);
```

I want to do something like this:

```rust
let data : [*mut NativeStructType; 2] = convert(ptr);
```

but how do I perform that conversion? This is basically the opposite of `.as_ptr()`.

The above is simplified; the actual function I'm trying to call is [z3_sys::Z3_mk_tuple_sort](https://docs.rs/z3-sys/0.6.3/z3_sys/fn.Z3_mk_tuple_sort.html) where I'm trying to decode the `proj_decl` out-parameter (ignore the documentation about the user needing to allocate memory, that's incorrect as far as I can tell).

Comment: You are probably looking for the `Box::from_raw()` function:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw

Comment: @8176135 from_raw should only be used with something create by into_raw.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html is what you seek but you can't have an array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a general answer to the question you've asked, **which might not work for the problem you have**:

You need to do the conversion in two stages. First, create a slice from using your knowledge of the start pointer and length:

```
let data_slice_ref = std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, 2);
```

This step has a lot of safety requirements – you're taking a non-Rust value and interpreting it as a Rust value. In particular, for this `_mut` version, you need to make sure that the pointer does indeed point to 2 consecutively allocated (and correctly initialized) `*mut NativeStructTypes` that belong to the same allocation and that will live long enough, that the pointer is correctly aligned, and that the number of bytes in the slice will fit in a `usize`. That last one isn't a problem here, and the other requirements will hopefully be upheld by the C++ library (but you do need to verify them). Additionally, and very importantly, you need to make sure that all reads and writes to the contents of the slice will go via the `&mut` reference you're creating for as long that it exists (this is a general safety requirement for all `&mut` references); this is both a requirement on the C++ code (say it gave you a pointer to a global variable, then that global variable will need to be unchanged by other code), and a requirement on your Rust code (now that you have your `&mut` reference, you mustn't access the bytes behind the slice via any other means).

Once you have your slice of known length, you can convert it to an array via `TryInto`:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;
let data: [*mut NativeStructType; 2] = data_slice_ref.try_into().unwrap();
```

(Here it's safe to use `unwrap()` rather a proper error handling routine because we created the slice to have length 2, so the conversion should never produce an error; the compiler's code generator will optimize the error check out, but the `unwrap()` is still needed so that the type checker doesn't complain.) This will copy the contents of the slice into an array, and is legal only because raw pointers are `Copy`; if you were working with values that might have nontrivial destructors or cloning rules, a better option would be to borrow rather than copy them, by using the `TryInto` implementation on `&mut [*mut NativeStructType; 2]` instead (although you would have to make very sure they would live long enough).

---

Anyway, I'm suspicious that your description of how `Z3_mk_tuple_sort` works may not be correct, for one specific reason: lifetimes. Both in C++ and in Rust, when you allocate something via a raw pointer API, you have to know how long it's allocated for, and deallocate it when you're done . `from_raw_parts_mut`, and its immutable friend `from_raw_parts`, don't know what the lifetime of the borrowed slice it's creating should be (because they're borrowing from a raw pointer, which has no lifetime information); Rust will trust your `unsafe` assertion that the raw pointer you're giving will live long enough, and will treat the slice as lasting for as long as you try to use it. But what is that lifetime, from C++'s point of view? Making sure that values live long enough is important in C++ as well as in Rust, and yet the documentation doesn't mention a lifetime for the buffer that's apparently being allocated.

The description in the documentation says that the buffer is provided by the caller, rather than newly allocated, which would make more sense; in that case, you wouldn't need this sort of conversion at all (you could just use `as_mut_ptr` on an `&mut [*mut NativeStructType; 2]` and pass that to `native_fn`). If it actually is being newly allocated, then presumably it lasts "until deallocated", which means that you'll have to figure out what the appropriate deallocation function is and call it once you're done with copying out of (or borrowing) your newly constructed slice. Another possibility is that it's returning a pointer to some sort of static buffer (which would be incredibly bad practice in Rust, and is bad practice in C++ too, but still seen on occasion), in which case you need to be very careful to make sure that you stop using your `&mut` borrow before the buffer gets overwritten. Either way, your description of how your native function works is either incorrect or incomplete, and as such, my answer based on your description may also end up not working for you until you figure out what the exact behaviour is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe the lifetime of the allocated memory is governed by the first function parameter, the `Z3_context`. There's a function [`Z3_del_context`](https://docs.rs/z3-sys/0.6.3/z3_sys/fn.Z3_del_context.html) you're supposed to call at the end of your program that I believe deallocates the memory. The `Z3_mk_tuple_sort` function also changes the value of both the `mk_tupl_decl` and `proj_decl` pointers (as in changes where they point to in memory), which is why I believe it must allocate the memory itself. I will try out this solution.